# Parse on SQL query

Tags: sql, parsing, time

from an old datatable (.dbf file) in a non formated column I got the a time value with 2 extra alphabetic letters. ejpl:**12:34:56AB**  = HH:mm:ssAB. The 2 letters stand for some userindefication(users inicials). How can I separate the time with this extra 2 letters in 2 different colums?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Standard SQL:

```
select substring(col from 1 for 8) as timepart,
       substring(col from 9) as initials
```

In case there are no initials this will return an empty string, Gordon's will return the seconds instead.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use `right()` and `left()`:

```
select right(timeval, 2) as initials,
       left(timeval, 8) as time
```

In fact, these functions are available in most databases.  And, all databases have similar functionality even if the functions are slightly different.